# Ошибка при получении запроса GET в Django

Tags: python, django

Есть данная функция на python, которая обрабатывает запрос из html формы, получает оттуда значение `q`, при вводе `"1"` в строку поиска выдает значение `"Ты пытаешься найти: u'1'"` Откуда появляется символ u'' и как его исправить понятия не имею, подскажите пожалуйста как пофиксить.

```
def search (request):
    if 'q' in request.GET:
       message = "Ты пытаешься найти: %r" % request.GET.get('q')
    else:
       message = "Пустая форма"
    return HttpResponse(message)

def search_form (request):
    return render_to_response('search_form.html')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%r` — это результат вызова функции `repr()`, которая для юникодовых строк представляет именно такую запись с префиксом `u`. Вам следует воспользоваться `%s` — это даст результат вызова `str()`.

Ну и в новом коде следует всё-таки переходить на использование функции `format()`:

```
"Ты пытаешься найти: {0}".format(request.GET.get('q'))
```

Comment: Отображение конечно исправляется и пропадает лишний символ, но исключение при пустой строке запроса все равно не срабатывает, сообщение "Пустая форма" не получаю

Comment: @Weit Ваше условие проверяет, что какое-то поле отсутствует, а не что оно пустое. При отправке пустой формы выполняется запрос `http://example.com/path?q=`, то есть значение `q` — пустая строка. Вам следует добавить в код проверку на пустую строку.

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало

Comment: @Weit тогда можно передать значение по умолчанию, например, пустую строку ```"Ты пытаешься найти: {0}".format(request.GET.get('q', ''))```